# use both beforeAction() and behaviors() method in controller in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-behaviors

I want to use both `beforeAction()` and `behaviors()` method in my controller.

If i add `beforeAction()` method in my code than `behaviors()` method is not working.

And if i remove  `beforeAction()` method than `behaviors()` method is working.

I dont want to remove `beforeAction()` as it is use to disable csrf  token for ajax calls.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
  if($action->id =='ignore' || $action->id =='accept')
  {
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And i want to use `behaviors()` method for authentication.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['create','index','update','change','view','page','active','list'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['create','index','update','change','view','page','active','list'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action)
                    {
                      echo "string";
                      die;
                    },
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl);
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

Is there any way to use both method in same controller.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
  if($action->id =='ignore' || $action->id =='accept')
  {
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
  }
  //return true;
  return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

you need to return the parent beforeAction()